# Retrieve inner type from anonymous pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, type-traits

I have got a complicated template type `X<..>*` returned from a function (it is a large template type with more than 200 chars length, so I do never want to write it). Inside this complicated type, there is a type `Y` which I want to retrieve:

```
// The template type with inner type
template<typename T>
struct X{
   typedef ... Y;
};

// The function returning a pointer to a very long instanication of X
X<...>* foo(){}
```

I am using `auto` to handle this long type and want to use `decltype` to get the inner type, like this:

```
int main(){
   auto t = foo(); 
   decltype(*t)::Y y; // This variable should be of the inner type
}
```

However, this does not work, since evaluating `*t` yields the type `X<...>&` instead of `X<...>`, so I cannot use scope resolution `::Y` on a reference. So how can I remove the reference easily so that I can access the inner type. I know of `std::remove_reference`, I could write the following:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(*t)>::type::Y y;
```

However, this will be used often and I don't want to clutter my code with excessive use of such a long type trait. So is there a syntatically shorter way of accessing the inner type `Y`, given that I have a variable of pointer type `X<..>*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
template <typename T>
using MyY = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type::Y;
```

you may do

```
MyY<decltype(*t)> y;
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

If there add a member function `foobar` with return type `Y` to the template, you can use:

```
decltype(t->foobar()) y
```